# Angular 2 D3 drag function scoping issue

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I am using d3.js v4.4 and Angular 2.

I have some bubble that's drag-gable and the drag works fine.  What i need to do now if access the drag-to x and y, use those values to calculate a value with my data set which sits on my component.  The problem I ran into is my drag end function, this refers to the dragged object, I have noway of access the actual parent scope.

this is how I added the bubble.

```
showPeopleBubble() {
        let self = this;
        console.log('run')
        this.bubblePeople = this.canvas.selectAll('.bubblePeople')
            .data(this.nodes)
            .enter().append('g')
            .attr('class','.bubblePeople').attr('id',function(d){return 'i'+d.index})
            .attr('transform',"translate(100,100)")
            .call(D3['drag']().on("start", self.dragstarted)
                .on("drag", self.dragged)
                .on("end", self.dragended));

            this.bubblePeople.append("title").text(function(d){return d.name + ' ('+d.index+')'})

            this.bubblePeople.append('circle')
                .attr('r',30)
                .attr('fill','blue')
                .attr('fill-opacity',.3)
                .attr("text-anchor","middle")

            this.bubblePeople.append('text').text(function(d){return d.name.substring(0,30/3)});

    }

dragended(d) {
   // this in here is the bubble that i'm dragging
//i need to access the parent level.


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually use the callback like this:

```
showPeopleBubble() {
        let self = this;
        console.log('run')
        this.bubblePeople = this.canvas.selectAll('.bubblePeople')
            .data(this.nodes)
            .enter().append('g')
            .attr('class','.bubblePeople').attr('id',function(d){return 'i'+d.index})
            .attr('transform',"translate(100,100)")
            .call(D3['drag']().on("start", self.dragstarted)
                .on("drag", self.dragged)
                .on("end", function(d){
                    return self.dragended(d, this, self);
                 }));

            this.bubblePeople.append("title").text(function(d){return d.name + ' ('+d.index+')'})

            this.bubblePeople.append('circle')
                .attr('r',30)
                .attr('fill','blue')
                .attr('fill-opacity',.3)
                .attr("text-anchor","middle")

            this.bubblePeople.append('text').text(function(d){return d.name.substring(0,30/3)});

    }

dragended(d, innerThis, globalThis) {
   // this in here is the bubble that i'm dragging
//i need to access the parent level.
  //  globalThis.someFunction();  <-- will call the global someFunction() method

}

someFunction(){}
```

I've also put the functions `this` so you won't lose it inside the `dragended(d)` function in the global scope.

Comment: thanks, didn't get to try this, I ended up using .bind(this)

Comment: @chungtinhlakho no problem, note that you will lose the event `this` if you bind the global this to the method. This might not be relevant for this issue but it will be relevant for events like `mouseclick`. Just to let you know.

Comment: good to know, thanks, I tried yours and works perfectly well and provide more flexibility as well.  thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

End up using .bind, I can bind this or the data that I needed.

```
.call(D3['drag']().on("start", self.dragstarted)
                .on("drag", self.dragged)
                .on("end", self.dragended.bind(this)));
```